# Bourbon/Neat VS 2017 unexpected character sequence

Tags: asp.net, sass, bourbon, neat

So, I installed bourbon and neat in my project. It's an ASP.NET application. I didn't set up gulp, I just downloaded it directly to my project in a file called _libraries. The tree is like this:

```
root
  -_resources
    -scss
        -_global
          - style.scss
        -_libraries
            -bourbon (folder)
            -bourbon.scss
            -neat (folder)
            -neat.scss
```

The bourbon folder, bourbon.scss, neat folder and neat.scss are siblings. They're just thrown in there in the same folder.

Now, I have them imported in  my style.scss:

```
@import "_libraries/bourbon";
@import "_libraries/neat";
```

Here's the weird part. Visual Studio is doing fine with the `@include`

but the moment I try to type:

```
$custom-grid--thirds: (
      columns: 3,
      gutter: 60px,
    );
```

for example I can see that under every ":" I get an 'unexpected character sequence error' and I don't think the grid works when it comes to html, while the includes do. I'm on this problem for 5 hours and I have no clue what's happening. Any help? I'm desperate kind of.

Edit: I fixed the root tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simple, but took me about 5 hours (Yes, I'm still a junior).

Visual Studio has no Intellisense for anything SASS. So, it should work, but VS will still won't see it as correct (even though it works).